# Sed - Conditionally match and add additional string after the find

Tags: macos, sed, bsd

Let's say I have a line like this in a file "config.xml"

`<widget android-packageName="com.myproject" android-versionCode="12334" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.myproject" ios-CFBundleVersion="12334" version="1.5.2" versionCode="1.5.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

And I want to use a line of command in sed to change it into this, which is adding ".1" after the current version numbers:

`<widget android-packageName="com.myproject" android-versionCode="12334" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.myproject" ios-CFBundleVersion="12334" version="1.5.2.1" versionCode="1.5.2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

Assuming the version number could change, which means I would likely need to match it as a string between "version="" and """ first then add something after. How should I achieve that?

---

Attempted code that was (wrongly) shown in the form of an answer:

```bash
sed -i '' -e 's/\" versionCode=\"/\.1\" versionCode=\"/g' config.xml
sed -i '' -e 's/\" xmlns=\"/\.1\" xmlns=\"/g' config.xml
```

Comment: @anubhava Not yet. I was trying to match the string in between but can't find a way to achieve it.

Comment: Why `sed` and not an XML parser? Why is the question tagged with [tag:linux], [tag:ios], and [tag:android]?

Comment: @miken32 Because the part I was changing is related to the deployment of ios and android, and the command is supposed to be working in both linux and macOS due to the specific requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` to append `.1` in version number of any field name starting with `version`:

```bash
sed -i.bak -E 's/( version[^=]*="[.0-9]+)/\1.1/g' file
```

**Output:**

> `<widget android-packageName="com.myproject" android-versionCode="12334.1" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.myproject" ios-CFBundleVersion="12334" version="1.5.2.1" versionCode="1.5.2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

**Breakup:**

- `(`: Start capture group

  - `version`: natch text `version`
  - `[^=]*`: match 0 or more of any character that is not `=`
  - `=`: match a `=`
  - `"`: match a `"`
  - `[.0-9]+`: match 1+ of any character that are digits or dot
- `)`: End capture group

Comment: Somehow that one doesn't work on my side (it doesn't change anything precisely). I am on macOS by the way.

Comment: I am also on macOS. Does above command write output on terminal?

Comment: It does show the output, but the change is not applied to the file... OK, adding `-i ''` would work. Thanks.

Comment: Just to note the change on `android-versionCode="12334.1"` should be avoided. Changing it to `sed -E 's/( version[^=]*="[.0-9]+)/\1.1/g' file` will do.